# Zero inflated negative binomial distribution expected frequency

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, zero-inflation

I have data vector and I am trying to do chi square test. This test use frequency from real data and expected frequency. 
my data

```
table(T1)
T1 
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  26 
 204  11   5  11   5   1   8   2   3   1   1   2   2   2   2   1
```

if I use R  to generate data set that follow my distribution results are quite close.

```
testiramo <- rZINBI(261, mu = 1.19, sigma = 3.13, nu = 0.78)
table(testiramo)
testiramo
  0   1   2   3   4   5   7  11 
237   9   3   7   1   2   1   1
```

mu = mean
sigma = std.deviation
nu = probability of zeroes

My questions are

1. How to calculate expected frequency for zero inflated negative binomial to compare with using chi square test?
2. is it possible to define range / level of overdispersion of data (as you can see in this generated sample of data have maximum value of 11 and mine is 26)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1.  The table you printed already has this.

Regarding 2. Not if you want to keep the other parameters (mu, sigma and nu) the same. I am assuming you got those from your data.

Comment: This parameters are from my real data. Should I mark this 26 as outliner and remove from dataset? What can be done to tweak this parameter sigma (since this is measure of distance from mean), and is there some procedure or test (MLE) for that (any reference to MLE will be great specially since I am using data vector and all examples I did find are for multivariate data).

Comment: If i do chi sqared test with my dataset (T1) and testiramo i have this result

Comment: chisq.test(T1, testiramo)  
  
 Pearson's Chi-squared test  
  
data:  T1 and testiramo  
X-squared = 295.23, df = 90, p-value < 2.2e-16  
Warning message:  
In chisq.test(T1, testiramo) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

Comment: is this small p value confirm that this come from same distribution? and how to interpret other results.

Comment: The small p value indicates _different_ results but you need an exact test.

Comment: what kind of different test is needed to confirm distribution?

Comment: It's quite clear that the two distributions are different.  But to show statistical evidence, you should use an exact test.